# Microsoft Access - Print Multiple reports at one button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query named "Query1" that contains "Report_Name" field. I have also three different Access Reports named "Rpt1, Prt3, and Rpt5". In each records will tell which report name that will be used.

I tried to use `if ... then myTestField.visable=true`, but there are too many text-fields in the query to declare in the code.

I also tried to use Subform (child in access?). `me.Report_Name = Reports.Rpt5`  in 'on Format' in the report form.

Both above cannot complete my need, I do not have much code yet. Is there any idea to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can show your code, sample data and expected result? I can't understand what you mean _multiple reports_, what `text-fields` are.  Moreover, are you going to use `VBA` or just command in access? For the `VBA`, please tag `vba` too.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess as to what you want to accomplish:

```
Private Sub ButtonPrint_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db=CurrentDB

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("YourQuery") 'Change this to your query name

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()

Do While Not rs.EOF
    DoCmd.OpenReport rs!Report_Name, acViewPreview, , , acHidden
    DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, rs!REPORT_NAME
    DoCmd.PrintOut acSelection
    DoCmd.Close acReport, rs!Report_Name
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

In short, this will open as many reports as rows your query has, in hidden mode and one at a time, printing one at a time as well.